# Can't convert from low voltage halogens to LEDs. Voltage is a mystery

Tags: wiring, led

I have undercabinet halogen/xenon bulbs.  They are reportedly 12V DC.  There is a transformer somewhere in the wall but I don't know where it is.

WHen I hook up 12V AC/DC LEDs to it, it flashes for an instant and then goes dead.  If I touch the wires together, they spark.  If I hook a multimeter up, I get the following.  Not sure why I don't get a reading that I understand.  Any help would be appreciated.[image: multimeter]

[image: multimeter]

Comment: Did you do it in that order? because when touching the wires together you probably tripped the fuse in the transformer.

Comment: Try working with at least 1 halogen hooked up.

Comment: Odds are good you're going to need to find the transformer and look at the specs to know exactly what it's putting out. If you're working off of guesses, things probably won't work out all that well. Try looking above upper cabinets and behind drawers in lower cabinets. Someone might have buried it in the wall - if so, that's a hint that they didn't do other things correctly either.

Comment: If you shorted out the transformer by touching the wires and having them spark, you might have to wait for it to reset.... or you might have to find it and reset it.... or you might have damaged it.